# How do I set an alarm in Linux for less than a second?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, alarm

I have been using the alarm() system call and an alarm handler in my c program. Recently I decided that I wanted to set the alarm for a time less than a second, so I passed it 0.5, and discovered that the alarm() function accepts an unsigned int. Is it possible to set an alarm for less than a second?

Comment: Others have suggested `ualarm`. While reading up on solution for your question, I learnt about `setitimer`, which can also solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`ualarm(usecs, interval)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ualarm) method instead.

Comment: `usecs or interval is not smaller than 1000000.` that is equal one second.